# Using CSS and XSL in XML

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have a project where I need a to convert an xml to html using an XSLT and have a css for it as well. I just can't seem to get the CSS to affect the document, any help would be great!

The CSS is just align center because I can easily see if it's working or not, once I know it's working I can edit it so it's how i want it to be. But basically the XSL works fine but I can't get the CSS to affect the xml

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="BookDescription.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="book_details.css"?>
<!--ORACLE BOOK-->
<Book>
    <bookID>0-07-882122-3</bookID>
    <bookTitle>Oracle: A Beginner's Guide</bookTitle>
    <bookCategory>database</bookCategory>
    <bookDescription>A beginner's guide to the complex and powerful Oracle database management system. Teaches you how to set up, query and manage your database, including principles of database design, how to manage data, generate reports and tune the system for optimal performance.</bookDescription>
    <bookPrice>30.00</bookPrice>
    <bookAuthor>Michael Abbey</bookAuthor>
    <bookImage>images/Oracle.JPG</bookImage>
    <bookInfo>Oracle.xml</bookInfo>
</Book>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Book">
        <h3>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookTitle"/>
        </h3>
        <img alt="">
            <xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="bookImage"/></xsl:attribute>
        </img>
        <div>
            <xsl:text>ISBN: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookID"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:text>Author: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookAuthor"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:text>Category: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookCategory"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:text>Description: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookDescription"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <xsl:text>Price: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bookPrice"/>
        </div>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Book"/>
            </body>
        </html> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CSS

```
div{
    text-align: center;
}

bookID{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML that was rendered?

Comment: When you say <xsl:template match="Book">, it is expecting to retrieve style information from a CSS file named "Book.CSS" is that the case?

Comment: @seva.rubbo `<html>
 <body>
  <h3>Oracle: A Beginner's Guide</h3><img alt="" src="images/Oracle.JPG"><div>ISBN: 0-07-882122-3</div>
  <div>Author: Michael Abbey</div>
  <div>Category: database</div>
  <div>Description: A beginner's guide to the complex and powerful Oracle database management system. Teaches you how to set up, query and manage your database, including principles of database design, how to manage data, generate reports and tune the system for optimal performance.</div>
  <div>Price: 30.00</div>
 </body>
</html>` hope that's code.

Comment: @AdibBehjat No, <xsl:template match="Book"> means it's going through my xml looking for <Book> which it finds one instance of and works accordingly, however my css has no effect on the file and my question is why isn't it having an effect

Comment: I don't see where you include your CSS. You don't even have a `head` element.

Comment: You're correct! Sorry, I'm new to this. The only other alternate solution I can think of is good ol' HTML by placing the link to css under <head>. Here is an example I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @seva.rubbo that might answer my question, can you not have an xsl and css work on an xml file? I convert it to html but i thought the css would take affect before the transformation so i was wondering why it wasn't showing up right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `link` to your CSS file:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/your/css/file.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Book"/>
        </body>
    </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

Or:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                /* Your CSS here */ 
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Book"/>
        </body>
    </html> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yup that did it, so that's a no to having an xsl and css working on the same xml file right?

Comment: @DrMoney. No, you can include CSS directly to your template. See the update.